# View details data from grid in new html page [OpenJS]

Tags: php, html

I am using the OpenJS grid perfectly! I have a grid with students. I can click on the student row and get the studendID. And I can open the StudentID.php without problem,

```
 $Students.on("rowClick", function (event, $row, rowData)
     {
         var SN = rowData.StudentID;
         var url = "StudentsInfo.php";
         $(location).attr('href',url);
```

But now I want to click on the student row and open a new window call StudentInfo.php that will display all info from the student and so on. How can I pass the vsr SN to the new html dynalmically?

How can i implent this new page (ex: /StudenteInfo?=John...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Students.on("rowClick", function (event, $row, rowData)
     {
         var SN = rowData.StudentID;
         var url = "StudentsInfo.php?studentID=" + SN;
         $(location).attr('href',url);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I need!
One more question please!
If I want to show a textbox on the new page with the studentID?

Comment: `<?php echo $_GET['studentID']; ?>`

Comment: I are truly a Master!! Las question please!
Now I want to connect the database to get the sutdent info. 
The SQL part I know. But in the SQL statement I have to use the WHERE clause where the StudentID = the current student. Where is the current student stored? Can I do var SN = $_GET['studentId'] on the new page?

Comment: I think I got it!
$SN = $_GET['SerialNumber'];